# gcc -v shows needed -ltbb is being skipped

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-reference

I have a link error with undefined symbols, e.g.

```
undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
```

My gcc options (passed through the [mainwin mwdip wrapper](http://www.mainsoft.com/content/mainsoft-unix-and-linux-overview)) has the following section:

```
-lxerces-c -ltbb -lboost_chrono
```

When I include verbose output with -v , I see the following section in the verbose output:

```
-lxerces-c -lboost_chrono
```

Why would the verbose output skip some -l args?

Does gcc try to ignore libraries it thinks it doesn't need?  Is there a way for me to force gcc to include a needed library that it is mistakenly thinking it can skip?

Comment: Copy-paste your command line (including -v) and output here?

Comment: I am not at liberty to copy and paste build commands from the proprietary software I work on.  I realize it may be unreasonable to answer my question specifically due to this, but I hope at least the generic question "Does gcc try to ignore libraries it thinks it doesn't need" is answerable.

Comment: @JDiMatteo It depends on where you have placed the -ltbb on the command line. You need to place it after any other objects/static/shared libraries that references it - which is why seeing the exact command line that gets executed for the linking stage is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some linker wrappers cannot handle linker scripts, so replace the libtbb.so linker script with a copy of libtbb.so.2 , e.g.

```
cp libtbb.so.2 libtbb.so
```

The [libtbb.so](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download) file is an ASCII text file with this contents:

```
INPUT (libtbb.so.2)
```

This is a [GNU ld linker script command](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/simple-commands.html).  Some more complex builds may not support this.  For example, if you include -v in the compiler options, you can see that the [mainwin gcc wrapper mwdip](http://www.mainsoft.com/content/mainsoft-unix-and-linux-overview) discards linker script command files in the verbose output list of libraries to link in.  A simple work around is to replace the linker script input command file with a copy of the file instead (or a symlink).

Answer (score 1):

GCC processes dependencies right-to-left. An undefined reference for a library that you're linking generally means that you're linking something that needs `tbb` after you linked `tbb` (and the linker doesn't go back and re-check `tbb` for the newly needed symbols).

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the problem.  I've tried including -ltbb last and there are no circular dependencies on it.  (I've also tried including it first, in the middle, and multiple times.)

Comment: @JDiMatteo - Other suggestions: add `-Wl,-t` to your linker command to make sure that the linker is using the `libtbb.so` you think it is. Run `nm -C --dynamic` on that `libtbb.so` to make sure it defines the symbols you think it does.

Comment: thanks for those suggestions.  Please consider closing this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/29350920#29350920